# Find email from ReceivedTime

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I try to find email from received time but somethings dont want to work. I dont get any error but the msg is not moving to diff folder

```
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItem As Object
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application

Set myNameSpace = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set myInbox = myNameSpace.Folders(user_email).Folders("RXXX")


Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders(fDestination)

Set myItems = myInbox.Items

Set myItem = myItems.Find("[ReceivedTime] = '#" + msg_date + "#'")

While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
MsgBox 1
    MoveItems = MoveItems + 1
    myItem.Move myDestFolder
    Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
Wend

Set myNameSpace = Nothing
Set myInbox = Nothing
Set myItems = Nothing
Set myDestFolder = Nothing
Set myItem = Nothing
```

Comment: Make sure `msg_date` is formatted like: `yyyy-mm-dd`, not `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: the date is yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: Where is msg_date? Value

Answer (score 0):

Format seems correct, but single quotes should not be present:

```
Set myItem = myItems.Find("[ReceivedTime] = #" + msg_date + "#")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `=` when working with DateTime properties - the condition will never be satisfied (even if you specify date and time down to the millisecond level) because of the round-off errors. Always use a range

```
@SQL=(ReceivedTime < '4/17/2020') AND (ReceivedTime > '4/1/2020')
```

Answer (score 0):

Date format is a major source of problems.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
'
' If desperate declare as variant


Sub findByReceivedTime_DateRange()

Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace

Dim mySourceFolder As Outlook.folder
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.folder
Dim fDestination As String

Dim myItems As Outlook.items
Dim myItem As Object

Dim msg_dateStart As Date
Dim msg_dateEnd As Date

Dim msg_dateStartStr As String
Dim msg_dateEndStr As String

Dim strFilter As String

Set myNamespace = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

' mySourceFolder under mailbox, not under inbox
Set mySourceFolder = myNamespace.folders(user_email)
Set mySourceFolder = mySourceFolder.folders("RXXX")

' myDestFolder under mySourceFolder
fDestination = "TestDest"
Set myDestFolder = mySourceFolder.folders(fDestination)

Set myItems = mySourceFolder.items
myItems.sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

Debug.Print myItems(1).ReceivedTime & ": " & myItems(1).Subject
Debug.Print

' Test with a number bigger than 12 for the day to verify date format
' Start of the range
msg_dateStart = Format(#3/26/2020#, "yyyy/mm/dd")
Debug.Print "msg_dateStart...: " & msg_dateStart

msg_dateStartStr = CStr(msg_dateStart)
Debug.Print "msg_dateStartStr: " & msg_dateStartStr

' For a single day, end of the range is the beginning of the next day
msg_dateEnd = Format(#3/27/2020#, "yyyy/mm/dd")
Debug.Print "msg_dateEnd.....: " & msg_dateEnd

msg_dateEndStr = CStr(msg_dateEnd)
Debug.Print "msg_dateEndStr..: " & msg_dateEndStr

strFilter = "[ReceivedTime] > '#" & msg_dateStartStr & "#'"
Debug.Print strFilter

strFilter = strFilter & " AND [ReceivedTime] < '#" & msg_dateEndStr & "#'"
Debug.Print strFilter

Set myItem = myItems.Find(strFilter)

While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
    Debug.Print myItem.Subject
    myItem.Move myDestFolder
    Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
Wend

End Sub
```